# Problem with the complemetary Fibonacci succession in Fortran

Tags: fortran, precision

I've been following this site for a while. I just wanted to ask a question regarding the output of my fortran90 program. The goal of the following program is to study if the succession defined like the inverse of Fibonacci's succession (a(n-1)/a(n)). I should be able to say if **abs(a(n-1)/a(n) - g ) < e** with e that goes from **1.E-6 to 1.E-20**, g is the complemetary constant obtained by subratracting one to the golden ratio phi,or by using the analytical formula (sqrt(5) -1)/2. Here it follows the program.

```
module precisione
implicit none 
   integer, parameter :: ik = selected_int_kind(33)        
   integer, parameter :: rk = selected_real_kind(33)   
   real (kind=rk),parameter :: g = (sqrt(5.) -1)/real(2)            
   real (kind=rk),parameter :: phi = (1+sqrt(5.))/real(2)  
   real,parameter :: e = 1.E-15
end module precisione

module successione                                         
use precisione
implicit none 
  contains
   recursive subroutine nonfidia(n,f,d,r)                 
    integer(kind=ik), intent(in) :: n                     
    integer(kind=ik), intent(out) :: f                    
    real(kind=rk),intent(out) :: d
    real(kind=rk),intent(out) :: r                           
    integer(kind=ik):: p,s                                
    if(n > 2) then                                      
      call nonfidia(n-1,s,d,r)                            
      call nonfidia(n-2,p,d,r)                            
      f = p+s                                          
      r = real(p)/real(s)                                
      d = abs(r-g)
    else                                                  
      f=1
      r=1
      d=1-g
    end if   
   end subroutine
end module

program calcoli
 use successione                  
 implicit none
   integer(kind=ik) :: n                               
   integer(kind=ik) :: f                               
   real(kind=rk) :: d                                     
   real(kind=rk) :: ratio                                 
   integer(kind=ik) :: i                                 
   read*, n                                                
   do i=1,n                                              
    call nonfidia(i,f,d,ratio)                            
    write(unit=800,fmt=*)i,f,ratio,d,e,g                  
    print*, i,f,ratio,d,e,g                                 
    if (d < e) then                                       
     print*, "inside range , ratio = ", ratio             
     exit                                                
    end if
   end do   
    if (d > e)then                                        
     print*,"not in range, add terms"   
    end if
   
end program
```

**THE PROBLEM** I can't go past 21 terms because at that point the difference goes to zero somehow,and it falls in the first **if** condition, in fact 0.0000 is < e for every epsilon we take in consideration. I don't think the problem is the subtractive cancellation cause usually u can solve that using higher precision by modifing the kind parameter. Here it is the output:

[Output of program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB1d0.png)

I don't know how to wrap my head around this.
Starting with 1.E-6 it did work and the out was at the 17th cycle of do, with 1.E-7 was at the 19th and it was coherent, but from 1.E-8 onwards I keep getting the same error message.
PLEASE HELP

```
 100
 1 1   1.00000000000000000000000000000000000        0.381965994834899902343750000000000000         1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 2 1   1.00000000000000000000000000000000000        0.381965994834899902343750000000000000         1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 3 2   1.00000000000000000000000000000000000        0.381965994834899902343750000000000000         1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 4 3  0.500000000000000000000000000000000000        0.118034005165100097656250000000000000         1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 5 5  0.666666686534881591796875000000000000         4.86326813697814941406250000000000000E-0002   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 6 8  0.600000023841857910156250000000000000         1.80339813232421875000000000000000000E-0002   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 7 13  0.625000000000000000000000000000000000         6.96599483489990234375000000000000000E-0003   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 8 21  0.615384638309478759765625000000000000         2.64936685562133789062500000000000000E-0003   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 9 34  0.619047641754150390625000000000000000         1.01363658905029296875000000000000000E-0003   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 10 55  0.617647051811218261718750000000000000         3.86953353881835937500000000000000000E-0004   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 11 89  0.618181824684143066406250000000000000         1.47819519042968750000000000000000000E-0004   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 12 144  0.617977499961853027343750000000000000         5.65052032470703125000000000000000000E-0005   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 13 233  0.618055582046508789062500000000000000         2.15768814086914062500000000000000000E-0005   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 14 377  0.618025779724121093750000000000000000         8.22544097900390625000000000000000000E-0006   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 15 610  0.618037164211273193359375000000000000         3.15904617309570312500000000000000000E-0006   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 16 987  0.618032813072204589843750000000000000         1.19209289550781250000000000000000000E-0006   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 17 1597  0.618034422397613525390625000000000000         4.17232513427734375000000000000000000E-0007   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 18 2584  0.618033826351165771484375000000000000         1.78813934326171875000000000000000000E-0007   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 19 4181  0.618034064769744873046875000000000000         5.96046447753906250000000000000000000E-0008   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 20 6765  0.618033945560455322265625000000000000         5.96046447753906250000000000000000000E-0008   1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 21 10946  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000         0.00000000000000000000000000000000000         1.00000000E-15  0.618034005165100097656250000000000000      
 inside range , ratio =   0.618034005165100097656250000000000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't been consistent with your use of real kinds, and in particular a lot of the arithmetic is being done with default kind, which is likely lower precision than you are requesting through use of the `rk` parameter. Below is a program that uses the higher precision consistently. Note

a) Constants have a kind as well, and without specifying anything they will be of default kind. If you want a different kind you need to explicitly say it

b) Unless you specify an extra optional argument the real function will also convert to default kind

c) I can't persuade code and lists to format properly together on Stackoverflow ...

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat fab.f90
Module precisione
  Implicit None 
  Integer, Parameter :: ik = selected_int_Kind(33)        
  Integer, Parameter :: rk = selected_real_Kind(33)   
  Real (kind=rk),Parameter :: g = (Sqrt(5.0_rk) -1.0_rk)/2.0_rk   
  Real (kind=rk),Parameter :: phi = (1.0_rk+Sqrt(5.0_rk))/2.0_rk  
  Real (kind=rk),Parameter :: e = 1.E-15_rk
End Module precisione

Module successione                                         
  Use precisione
  Implicit None 
Contains
  Recursive Subroutine nonfidia(n,f,d,r)                 
    Integer(kind=ik), Intent(in) :: n                     
    Integer(kind=ik), Intent(out) :: f                    
    Real(kind=rk),Intent(out) :: d
    Real(kind=rk),Intent(out) :: r                           
    Integer(kind=ik):: p,s                                
    If(n > 2) Then                                      
       Call nonfidia(n-1,s,d,r)                            
       Call nonfidia(n-2,p,d,r)                            
       f = p+s                                          
       r = Real(p, Kind = Kind( r ) )/Real(s, Kind = Kind( r ) )                                
       d = Abs(r-g)
    Else                                                  
       f=1
       r=1.0_rk
       d=1.0_rk-g
    End If
  End Subroutine nonfidia
End Module successione

Program calcoli
  Use successione                  
  Implicit None
  Integer(kind=ik) :: n                               
  Integer(kind=ik) :: f                               
  Real(kind=rk) :: d                                     
  Real(kind=rk) :: ratio                                 
  Integer(kind=ik) :: i                                 
  Read*, n                                                
  Do i=1,n                                              
     Call nonfidia(i,f,d,ratio)                            
     Write(unit=800,fmt=*)i,f,ratio,d,e,g                  
     Print*, i,f,ratio,d,e,g                                 
     If (d < e) Then                                       
        Print*, "inside range , ratio = ", ratio             
        Exit                                                
     End If
  End Do
  If (d > e)Then                                        
     Print*,"not in range, add terms"   
  End If

End Program calcoli
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran -O -fcheck=all -Wall -Wextra -std=f2008 fab.f90
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
100
 1 1   1.00000000000000000000000000000000000        0.381966011250105151795413165634361840         9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 2 1   1.00000000000000000000000000000000000        0.381966011250105151795413165634361840         9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 3 2   1.00000000000000000000000000000000000        0.381966011250105151795413165634361840         9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 4 3  0.500000000000000000000000000000000000        0.118033988749894848204586834365638160         9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 5 5  0.666666666666666666666666666666666635         4.86326779167718184620798323010284749E-0002   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 6 8  0.599999999999999999999999999999999981         1.80339887498948482045868343656381790E-0002   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 7 13  0.625000000000000000000000000000000000         6.96601125010515179541316563436184030E-0003   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 8 21  0.615384615384615384615384615384615414         2.64937336527946358920221898102274545E-0003   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 9 34  0.619047619047619047619047619047619066         1.01363029772419941446078468198090626E-0003   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 10 55  0.617647058823529411764705882352941154         3.86929926365436439880952012697005884E-0004   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 11 89  0.618181818181818181818181818181818168         1.47829431923333613594983816180008114E-0004   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 12 144  0.617977528089887640449438202247191017         5.64606600072077551486321184471430512E-0005   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 13 233  0.618055555555555555555555555555555577         2.15668056607073509687211899174172578E-0005   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 14 377  0.618025751072961373390557939914163083         8.23767693347481402889445147507700748E-0006   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 15 610  0.618037135278514588859416445623342130         3.14652861974065482961125770397041390E-0006   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 16 987  0.618032786885245901639344262295081946         1.20186464894656524257207055621363756E-0006   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 17 1597  0.618034447821681864235055724417426583         4.59071787016030468890051788423244255E-0007   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 18 2584  0.618033813400125234815278647463994977         1.75349769613389308186901643182656767E-0007   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 19 4181  0.618034055727554179566563467492260061         6.69776593313619766331266219010299554E-0008   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 20 6765  0.618033963166706529538387945467591504         2.55831883186661988888980466554972085E-0008   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 21 10946  0.618033998521803399852180339985218040         9.77190855164759350561957988060738922E-0009   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 22 17711  0.618033985017357938973140873378403072         3.73253690923144596098723508783041383E-0009   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 23 28657  0.618033990175597086556377392580881950         1.42570223835179055821524379070670731E-0009   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 24 46368  0.618033988205325051470844819764804385         5.44569796733742014600833774707823291E-0010   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 25 75025  0.618033988957902001380262249827467253         2.08007153175675415461829093100635152E-0010   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 26 121393  0.618033988670443185604798400533155613         7.94516625997884338324825462573575097E-0011   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 27 196418  0.618033988780242682856507376866870418         3.03478346519205425012322582668039137E-0011   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 28 317811  0.618033988738303006852732437963934105         1.15918413518543964017040549735541358E-0011   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 29 514229  0.618033988754322537608830405492572618         4.42768940424357112693445786493866695E-0012   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 30 832040  0.618033988748203621343798191078293911         1.69122686078864328734424877133339579E-0012   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 31 1346269  0.618033988750540839382721984519974993         6.45991178135150154336833610760961439E-0013   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 32 2178309  0.618033988749648101530971893432887521         2.46746673614940932750639110506896385E-0013   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 33 3524578  0.618033988749989097047296779290725048         9.42488427099449250868884736278446728E-0014   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 34 5702887  0.618033988749858848350071980248415539         3.59998545148541172226208047535336351E-0014   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 35 9227465  0.618033988749908598925421457588060227         1.37507208346232224220669885957802422E-0014   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 36 14930352  0.618033988749889595896597819661196270         5.25230798901470444188988345745259482E-0015   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160      
 37 24157817  0.618033988749896854407719255379913368         2.00620313242101427520822532300926455E-0015   9.99999999999999999999999999999999987E-0016  0.618033988749894848204586834365638160
```

Note I killed the program before it completed

Comment: WOW that was fast! But what u mean in point b)? For everything else I get it. Completely forgot about _rk attached to parameters and so on. Thx  a lot

Comment: Real( a ) returns a real value of default kind. Real( a, rk ) returns a real  of kind rk, assuming rk to be a valid kind for reals. They are not necessarily the same.

Comment: Curious, does Fortran cause a stackoverflow with recursive functions like C-based languages when each recursive call stores a frame to the stack, running out of space after 30-40 recursions.

Comment: Implementation dependent. The standard says nothing about how the implementation deals with this, or to my knowledge anything else in Fortran. Nothing stopping it being turned into an iteration. My belief is C is the same, but my knowledge is less good there.